# Trouble understanding parameter substitution in a script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand a bash [script](http://mostly.harmless.evilcoder.org/2011/file-integrity-on-mac-os-x/) whose first four lines are:

```
#!/bin/sh
SCRIPT="`basename $0 | sed 's/\..*$//'`"
CONFIG=${1:-$HOME/.$SCRIPT}
DIR=${2:-$HOME/Documents}
```

I understand that the last two lines are doing parameter substitution on paths input as script arguments 1 and 2, but I've been unable to figure out how this works (e.g. [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSUB2)).  What does the ":-" part mean?  Sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man bash`:

```
   ${parameter:-word}
          Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Other‐
          wise, the value of parameter is substituted.
```

Very easy to find, with `man bash`, and then <kbd>/</kbd>`:-`. The slash introduces a search, and `:-` is just the content to search for. Else, searching in bash can get very boring, because it is huge, but here it is the first hit.

Comment: Apologies.  Didn't think to look _there_.