# Esoteric shell script syntax

Tags: shell, syntax

I've found this in a shell script that I use and I'm having trouble finding a formal description/definition of this syntax:

```
ACTION=${1:-update}
```

I'm assuming that if $1 variable does not exist (no command line arguments) then "-update" is used.

Comment: Exact duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10390406/495451), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10287197/495451)

Answer (score 1):

It's not esoteric. It's POSIX, and even Bourne. In every shell manpage ever. `man bash` or `man ksh`. The assumption is mostly right, if the parameter `1` is unset or empty string, then expand the alternate.

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02